# How to iterate next and previous in multiple lists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have lists like this. when i click next and previous i want to iterate through all the list items. if one section-content finishes on next it should goto next section-content list item. How can i do it.

```
<ul class="main-section">
        <li class="section">
            <div class="section-header">
            </div>
            <ul class="section-content">
                <li class="content-item current">
                </li>
                <li class="content-item">
                </li>
                <li class="content-item">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="section">
            <div class="section-header">
            </div>
            <ul class="section-content">
                <li class="content-item">
                </li>
                <li class="content-item">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

My next and previous click function are as below

```
$('.right').click(function () {
    $('.current').next().trigger('click');
});
$('.left').click(function () {
    $('.current').prev().trigger('click');
});
```

On click item is

```
$(".content-item").click(function () {
   $(".current").removeClass("current");
   $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var allListItems = document.querySelectorAll("li.content-item");

$('.right').click(function () {
   goTo(1);
});
$('.left').click(function () {
    goTo(-1);
});

function goTo(direction){
    
    //default the direction = forward (+1)
    direction = direction || 1;
    
    var currentItem = document.querySelector('li.current');
    var currentIndex = Array.from(allListItems).indexOf(currentItem);
    
    var newIndex = currentIndex + (direction);
    
    //make sure that the index is never lower or higher 
    //than the number of items available
    newIndex = newIndex > allListItems.length-1 ? 0 : newIndex;
    newIndex = newIndex < 0 ? allListItems.length-1 : newIndex;
    
    allListItems[currentIndex].classList.remove('current');
    allListItems[newIndex].classList.add('current');
}
```

```css
.section-header:after{
    content: "Section Header";
}
li.content-item:after{
    content:"Hello";
}

li.current{
    background-color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main-section">
        <li class="section">
            <div class="section-header">
            </div>
            <ul class="section-content">
                <li class="content-item">
                </li>
                <li class="content-item current">
                </li>
                <li class="content-item">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="section">
            <div class="section-header">
            </div>
            <ul class="section-content">
                <li class="content-item">
                </li>
                <li class="content-item">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    
    <button class="left">left</button>
    <button class="right">right</button>
```

The reason it wasn't working in your example was due to `next()` and `prev()`, these functions looking for the next **SIBLING** in your current elements parent...

Thats the reason it wasn't jumping to the next `li` because it is in a different `parent`

---

see: https://api.jquery.com/next/

> Description: Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

The important part here is **SIBLING**

---

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just write code for them.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is purely jquery based in which i find the next and prev DOM occurance

```js
var counter = 0
$('.next').click(function(e){
if($('.content-item').eq(counter+1).length>0)
counter+=1;
else 
counter =0
var index =$('.content-item').eq(counter-1).removeClass('current');
var index =$('.content-item').eq(counter).addClass('current');
})
$('.prev').click(function(e){
if($('.content-item').eq(counter-1).length>0)
counter-=1;
else 
counter =-1
var index =$('.content-item').eq(counter+1).removeClass('current');
var index =$('.content-item').eq(counter).addClass('current');
})
```

```css
.section-header:after{
    content: "Section Header";
}
li.content-item:after{
    content:"Hello";
}

li.current{
    background-color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main-section">
        <li class="section">
            <div class="section-header">
            </div>
            <ul class="section-content">
                <li class="content-item current">
                </li>
                <li class="content-item">
                </li>
                <li class="content-item">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="section">
            <div class="section-header">
            </div>
            <ul class="section-content">
                <li class="content-item">
                </li>
                <li class="content-item">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button class="next">NEXT</button>
    <button class="prev">PREV</button>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just write code for them.